# Remove groupbs with groupby if row does not contain a pattern in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hel lo, I have a dataframe such as

```
col1 col2
G1 OP2
G1 OP0
G1 OPP
G1 OPL_Lh
G2 OII
G2 OIP
G2 IOP
G3 TYU
G4 TUI
G4 TYUI
G4 TR_Lh
```

and i would like to groupby and remove from the df tha groups that does not contain at leats one row in col2 that contain

```
'_Lh'
```

here I should only keep `G1` and `G4` and get :

```
col1 col2
G1 OP2
G1 OP0
G1 OPP
G1 OPL_Lh
G4 TUI
G4 TYUI
G4 TR_Lh
```

Does someone have an idea ? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC,

you can use a boolean test and `isin` to filter in the groups that contain `_Lh`

```
m = df[df['col2'].str.contains('_Lh')]['col1']

df[df['col1'].isin(m)].groupby('col1')...
```

---

```
print(df[df['col1'].isin(m)])

   col1    col2
0    G1     OP2
1    G1     OP0
2    G1     OPP
3    G1  OPL_Lh
8    G4     TUI
9    G4    TYUI
10   G4   TR_Lh
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```py
filter_=df.loc[df["col2"].str.contains("_Lh"), "col1"].drop_duplicates()

df=df.merge(filter_, on="col1")
```

Outputs:

```py
  col1    col2
0   G1     OP2
1   G1     OP0
2   G1     OPP
3   G1  OPL_Lh
4   G4     TUI
5   G4    TYUI
6   G4   TR_Lh
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a long way to solve this, to illustrate how `groupby` works.

**Begin by creating a function which tests for the string you want:**

```
def contains_str(x, string = '_Lh'):
    if string in x:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

**Next, iterate over your groups and apply this function:**

```
keep_dict = {}

for label, group_df in df.groupby('col1'):
    keep = group_df['col2'].apply(contains_str).any()
    keep_dict[label] = keep

print(keep_dict)
# {'G1': True, 'G2': False, 'G3': False, 'G4': True}
```

> Feel free to print individual items in the operation to understand their role.

**Finally, map that dictionary to your current df:**

```
df_final = df[df['col1'].map(keep_dict)].reset_index(drop=True)

    col1    col2
0   G1      OP2
1   G1      OP0
2   G1      OPP
3   G1      OPL_Lh
4   G4      TUI
5   G4      TYUI
6   G4      TR_Lh
```

---

**You can condense these steps using the following code:**

```
keep_dict = df.groupby('col1', as_index=True)['col2'].apply(lambda arr: any([contains_str(x) for x in arr])).to_dict()

print(keep_dict)
# {'G1': True, 'G2': False, 'G3': False, 'G4': True}
```

> I hope this both answers your Q and explains what's taking place "behind the scenes" in groupby operations.

Comment: @Grendel this should not be the accepted answer, the pandas API is built to explicitly avoid looping and `apply` should only be used as a last resort. use vectorised operations which take advantage of the core pandas code which is written in `C`

Comment: See final step @Datanovice `"...condense..."` – there are plenty reasons to accept this answer –> code is resilient to dynamic input, can handle groupby conditions etc.

Comment: Your final step is using apply, there is no need for it.

Comment: There are plenty reasons to use `apply`

Comment: have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @Datanovice – I'll keep in mind in the future.